# Array element mysteriously overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm learning p5.js.

I have a function that is called in setup() (don't worry, just the call is in setup, it is defined elsewhere):

```
CreateMaze = () => {
  for(let i = 1; i <= numTiles; i++) {
    let newTile = CreateTile(i);
    let tileAdded = false;
    while(!tileAdded) {
      for(let j = 0; j < tiles.length; j++) {
        print('new tile ' + newTile.x + ' ' + newTile.y);
        print('array tile ' + tiles[j].x + ' ' + tiles[j].y);
        if(newTile.x == tiles[j].x && newTile.y == tiles[j].y) {
          print('new tile ' + newTile.x + ' ' + newTile.y);
          print('array tile ' + tiles[j].x + ' ' + tiles[j].y);
          newTile = CreateTile(i);
        } else {
          tiles.push(newTile);
          tileAdded = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also in setup(), I create a tile with `let centralTile = new Tile(floor(windowWidth/2), floor(windowHeight/2),'#4caf50');` and push it to an array by `tiles.push(centralTile);`.

`CreateTile` is:

```
CreateTile = (ndx) => { 
  print('creating tile; index: ' + ndx);
  let dir = ChooseDir(); //choose a direction
  print(dir);
  let xoff, yoff;
  switch(dir) { //assign an offset value
    case "N": xoff = 0; yoff = -50; break;
    case "E": xoff = 50; yoff = 0; break;
    case "S": xoff = 0; yoff = 50; break;
    case "W": xoff = -50; yoff = 0; break;
  }

  //create a tile based on previous tile's location
  let newTile = new Tile(tiles[ndx - 1].x + xoff, tiles[ndx - 1].y + yoff);
  print('new tile ' + newTile.x + ' ' + newTile.y);
  print('array tile (' + ndx-1 + ') ' + tiles[ndx-1].x + ' ' + tiles[ndx-1].y);
  return newTile;
}
```

I'm running into an issue where the first tile I created in setup is the same as the second that comes from `CreateTile()`. I used the `print` statements to see where the value for the first tile is changing. It is right before the `if`. After I create the second tile, the `prints` tell me the two are different. But just before I compare them, they are the same. I cannot figure out why/how I'm changing the values of this initial array item. There is nothing I can find that would suggest it's changing. Like I said, when I create a second tile, it is different from the first (like it should be). But when it comes time to compare, they are the same. Where is this change occurring?

Comment: Break the `for .. j` loop after the tile has been pushed to the array.

Comment: That `while` in there makes me think there's a whole different problem here... If you're creating a maze of size `x*y`, why do you need more than the 2 `for` loops for `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Teemu That worked. I can't believe I didn't catch that. No more late night coding I guess.

Comment: @Cebrus I'm not creating a maze of size x*y. A single tile in the maze is positioned at x,y and I have numtiles tiles. The while loop is to have all different tile locations.